# Couchdb access from external IP

Tags: android, couchdb, acra

I'm trying to get access from an external PC to my couchdb.
   I've installed (replicated) acralyzer and acra-distributuin on my coucdb.
   Locally, all works, but externally not (from another pc into the same net, from a mobile...)

My bind_address on default.ini is 0.0.0.0. And it is run because the output of netstat -a displays:

```
     TCP    0.0.0.0:5984           GM-TEST:0              LISTENING
```

I don't understand what's wrong.
  Could you give me some help.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a CORS issue?

you may want to enable enable_cors to true in the configuration database. This should allow external IPs to retrieve results from CouchDB. But exposing DB directly on the network is not a best practice.